# How to handle close event of PowerShell window if user clicks on Close('X') button

Tags: powershell

I want to run some code before PowerShell 2.0 window is closed. For this I tried:

*PS > register-engineevent PowerShell.Exiting -action {get-process | out-file c:\work\powershellexiteventcalled.txt}*

It works fine if user closes PowerShell window using exit command (i.e. exit ). **But it does not work if user closes it by clicking on Close ('X') button on top right.**

I could not find any way to handle this. I also tried to do it the following way, but this does not work either:

PS > $query = "Select * from __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name='powershell.exe'"

PS > Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -Action {get-process | out-file c:\work\powershellexiteventcalled.txt}

Please guide how I can achieve this task.

---

UPDATE: With some useful input from a helpful professional online I also tried the following:

> $appCurrentDomain = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain
>   Register-ObjectEvent -Action {get-process | out-file c:\work\powershellexiteventcalled.txt} -InputObject $appCurrentDomain -EventName DomainUnload

But again, it does not work. As per Microsoft "DomainUnload event occurs when an AppDomain is about to be unloaded.". But it does not work when I close the window ( or even type exit  for that matter).

UPDATE:

With some help from other professionals online & a little effort I could achieve this with following code.

```
PS..> $code = @"

        using System;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        using System.Management.Automation;
        using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

        namespace MyNamespace
        {
            public static class MyClass
            {
                public static void SetHandler()
                {
                    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(new HandlerRoutine(ConsoleCtrlCheck), true);
                }

                private static bool ConsoleCtrlCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType)
                {
                    switch (ctrlType)
                    {
                        case CtrlTypes.CTRL_C_EVENT:
                            Console.WriteLine("CTRL+C received!");
                            return false;

                        case CtrlTypes.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
                            Console.WriteLine("CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT received!");
                            return true;

                        case CtrlTypes.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
                            Console.WriteLine("CTRL+BREAK received!");
                            return false;

                        case CtrlTypes.CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
                            Console.WriteLine("User is logging off!");
                            return false;

                        case CtrlTypes.CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
                            Console.WriteLine("User is shutting down!");
                            return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                [DllImport("Kernel32")]
                public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);

                // A delegate type to be used as the handler routine
                // for SetConsoleCtrlHandler.
                public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

                // An enumerated type for the control messages
                // sent to the handler routine.
                public enum CtrlTypes
                {
                    CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
                    CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
                    CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
                    CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
                    CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
                }
            }
        }"@

PS..> $text = Add-Type  -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
PS..> $rs = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace]::DefaultRunspace
PS..> [MyNamespace.MyClass]::SetHandler()
```

BUT THERES AN ISSUE I AM FACING.... If I run any cmdlet on console after registering this handler (e.g. get-date, get-process). Then the application will crash whenever an event occurs (e.g. Ctrl+C, close). Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't do this. The only time an exiting event will get called is if you type "exit" at the PowerShell prompt.

This is how I hook up my exiting event:

```
 $null = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier `
     ([System.Management.Automation.PsEngineEvent]::Exiting) -Action { # Put code to run here }
```

Comment: with some help from other professionals online & a little effort I could achieve this with following code.

Comment: PS v3 hooked the window close button up to the exiting event

Answer (score 1):

The unhandled exception occurs because garbage collection has already disposed your handler by the time the unmanaged method is called. You can get around that by storing it in a static field:

```
private static HandlerRoutine s_rou;

public static void SetHandler()
{
    if (s_rou == null)
    {
        s_rou = new HandlerRoutine(ConsoleCtrlCheck);
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(s_rou, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the X to close you are closing the application hosting PowerShell. This application would need to handle the exit situation. I believe the default PS host is the Windows console which is obviously not doing what you need. You could host PowerShell in a [custom host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and handle the exit events. I'm on a Mac right now but maybe running under the PS ISE would handle this for you?

Comment: I think you can't handle that at all with a console application, anyway. Technically I guess you are closing conhost which terminates the application it is hosting (which is hosting PowerShell).