# How much time did I spend at powershell?

Tags: powershell, stopwatch

Powershell using the **$profile** file, I want to find out how much time I spend on powershell every time it happens, print it to a file.

for example

```
24.11.2018, 13:41 -  1 hour 23 minute 12 second
11.11.2018, 13:41 -  2 hour 3 minute 2 second
11.11.2018, 13:41 -  1 hour 43 minute 42 second
...
...
```

The contents of a file named **ps_time_history.txt** are shown above.
I turned on the powershell screen 3 times and it shows how long it is on.

I've written a script as below, but I can't get the solution as I want.

I wrote a script into the **$profile** file as below, but I can't get the solution the way I want it.

```
Start-Job  -scriptblock 
{ 
  $StopWatch = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
  $StopWatch.Start();

  $date=((Get-Process -Name powershell | Sort-Object StartTime | where { $_ }).StartTime | Select -Last 1);
  $id=((Get-Process -Name powershell | Sort-Object StartTime | where { $_  }).id | select -Last 1 );


  while ($StopWatch.IsRunning)
   {
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
      if((Get-Process -id $id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
      {
        $time=[string]$StopWatch.Elapsed.Hours+":"+[string]$StopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes+":"+[string]$StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds;
        echo  ([string]$date+" - "+$time) >> ~\Desktop\ps_time_history.txt;
      }
      else
      {  
       $StopWatch.Stop();
      }
   }
 }
```

I got the date and id number of the recently opened powershell app.
The timer is running as long as the powershell screen is on.
The timer needs to stop when the powershell screen is turned off.

The script I'm writing is doing the **ps_time_history.txt** file every second.
But I don't want that.
Let Powershell write down how much time I spent when I closed it.

```
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 1
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 2
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 3
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 4
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 5
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 6
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 7
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 8
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 9
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 10
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 11
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 12
11/29/2018 02:23:17 - 0: 0: 13
```

This problem seems a little complicated.
How can I solve this problem or is there a shorter way?

Comment: What do you mean by the "PowerShell screen" being "on" or "turned off"?  It seems that you want to track the duration of the interactive PowerShell session/process, but do you mean more specifically the amount of time the window is active/focused (even harder to track)?  Also, I think something like `$processStartTime = Get-Date` at the beginning of your script would be sufficient to calculate durations instead of messing with a `Stopwatch`.  Keep in mind, too, that `Get-Process -Name powershell` could return PowerShell processes other than the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you want to log session duration with second-accuracy, instead of messing with a `Stopwatch` I think it'd be sufficient to simply store the session start time and calculate the duration from there...

```
$sessionStartTime = Get-Date;
```

There's a negligible difference, but if you wanted to start "counting" not from when the session becomes "available" but when the process starts, you could use the [`$PID` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#pid) to get the PowerShell process instance and save its [`StartTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.starttime) property...

```
$sessionStartTime = Get-Process -Id $PID | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'StartTime';
```

This complete `$PROFILE` script works for me using the [`Exiting` engine event](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-engineevent) to run a `ScriptBlock` when the session is ending:

```
[DateTime] $sessionStartTime = Get-Date;

Register-EngineEvent `
    -SourceIdentifier ([System.Management.Automation.PsEngineEvent]::Exiting) `
    -SupportEvent `
    -Action {
        [DateTime] $sessionExitTime = Get-Date;
        [TimeSpan] $sessionDuration = $sessionExitTime - $sessionStartTime;
        [String] $logLine = "$sessionExitTime - $sessionDuration";

        $logLine >> '~\Desktop\ps_time_history.txt';
    };
```

Note that this only handles the case of typing `exit` at the console.  The logging code is not run [when clicking the Close ("X") button on the PowerShell console window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8353581/150605).

Using the default formatting for `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` this outputs:

```
11/28/2018 18:26:48 - 00:00:03.1026319
```

If you don't want the duration to include fractional seconds you can use [custom `TimeSpan` formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) like this...

```
[String] $logLine = '{0:d} {0:HH\:mm\:ss} - {1:HH\:mm\:ss}' -f $sessionExitTime, $sessionDuration;
```

Comment: The script you wrote helped me solve my problem, and I did a bit of current.I share the script to help the developers with the same problem. `
$sessionStartTime = Get-Date;
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent -Action {
    
        $sessionExitTime = Get-Date;
        $diff= New-TimeSpan -Start $sessionStartTime -End $sessionExitTime;
        $time=[string]$sessionStartTime + " - " +[string]$diff.Hours+"hour "+[string]$diff.Minutes+"minute "+ [string]$diff.Seconds+"second";
        $time >> '~\Desktop\ps_time_history.txt';
}
`

Answer (score 1):

There are also some built in event logs. For example the code below will list times when powershell was started/exited within last 10 minutes (but it will not capture exits with X button)

```
$filter = @{ LogName='Windows Powershell'; StartTime=(get-date).AddMinutes(-10); EndTime=(Get-Date) } 
 Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter | Sort-Object TimeCreated | where {$_.id -in 400, 403}
```

Comment: the solution is not exactly that.Bacon helped solve my problem.
Thanks again for your help @mike-twc