# PowerShell track history as full objects across sessions

Tags: powershell, psreadline, command-history

I am a novice using PowerShell 5.1 under Win 10.
I am tinkering with history. So far, I managed to have a persistent history across sessions with `PSReadline`. <sup>*</sup>

But this is a "limited" persistent history, as only commands are saved in a text file, which is read when launching a new session. So a lot of information on the [HistoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.historyinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) objects is lost, in particular the [StartExecutionTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.historyinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#properties).
Then,

1. `Get-Content (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath` gives all commands with no "timestamp", and
2. `Get-History` gives commands with timestamp but only for the current session.

I am used to `history` in `bash`, which gets both points right.

[This old doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee156792(v=technet.10)) (2009) shows a possible workaround.
I managed to export all history info before leaving a session with `Get-History | Export-Clixml $env:PSDIR'\my_history.xml'`.
Executing `Import-Clixml $env:PSDIR'\my_history.xml' | Add-History` at the beginning of a new session recovers the full history, including timestamps.

What is missing, I guess, is:

1. A way to automatically export history upon closing the session.
   I don't even know if this is possible.
2. <s>Removing the first line in the history after importing, as it contains the importing command itself. I didn't work on this, but I guess I can handle it.</s>
   Not needed. If the importing command is executed in startup scripts it does not go to history.

**Is this a viable way to achieve the intended result?**
**If so, how could I incarnate item 1?**

**Are there any alternatives?**

---

<sup>* Although [I could not make it work in the PS ISE](https://superuser.com/questions/1567422/powershell-persistent-history-in-the-ise).</sup>

Comment: Have a look at the Add-History cmdlet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/add-history?view=powershell-7

Comment: @RetiredGeek - I checked the doc. I didn't find how it helps beyond what I already posted in the OP. I would appreciate if you have a more specific suggestion.

Comment: See the answer by Aaron Jensen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353581/how-to-handle-close-event-of-powershell-window-if-user-clicks-on-closex-butt. With that information you should be able to run the code have above to save history upon exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [the pointer by RetiredGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882382/powershell-track-history-as-full-objects-across-sessions/62886919#comment111206138_62882382), I could move forward.
What I did:

1. Added `Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action { . $env:PSDIR'\history\save_history.ps1' }` to my `profile.ps1`.
2. Created file `$env:PSDIR'\history\save_history.ps1'`
   containing `Get-History | Export-Clixml $env:PSDIR'\my_history.xml'`

This almost provides a solution.
The only two remaining issues are:

1. Removing the `exit` command that is left as the last command in history.
   This seems manageable.
2. Make this work when closing by hitting "X".<sup>*</sup>
   In this case, I have observed a strange result. If I close session #1 with "X", and open a new session #2, the commands that I have entered in session #1 do not show up at the bottom of `Get-History`.
   Nevertheless, they are available with Up/Dpwn arrows.
   This is likely worth another question.

---

<sup>* As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353581/how-to-handle-close-event-of-powershell-window-if-user-clicks-on-closex-butt#comment24116720_8429920), starting with PS v3 the "X" button was hooked up with the exit event. But "X" does not seem to work exactly like `exit`, given point 2 above.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but thought i'd share.

in the past i took a long time moving off windows 8.1 and was managing my history without psreadline and just powershells add- clear- get- history commands.
I wanted to save the history to a file and when loading a new session, have it read in the file.

I'd done the same using the Register-EngineEvent, but got frustrated losing the history if the terminal crashed or I 'x'ed out by mistake.

While I dont use the trick anymore, I did for a while. The trick was to have a snippet in my prompt function to append the last item in get-history to a csv file. Sure its ugly and a write to disk for each command you issue, but it worked for me and in case it tickles your fancy it worked like this:

- set some environment variable to save the history too in you profile.
- check if the file exists and add the history from it in your profile
- create a custom prompt that appends the last item from get-history to the csv file.

so for example in your profile

```
# in your profile somewhere 
$Env:MyPoshHistory = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\MyPoshHistory.csv"
If ( Test-Path $Env:MyPoshHistory ) { 
  Add-History -InputObject $( Import-Csv $Env:MyPoshHistory )
}
```

and then in your prompt add

```
If ($Env:MyPoshHistory) {
  Get-History | Select-Object -Last 1  | Export-Csv $Env:MyPoshHistory -Append
}
```

If your not sure how to add to your prompt, (which is just a function in powershell), see https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-prompt.html

easiest way is to define a function called prompt in your profile

```
   function prompt { 
    If ($Env:MyPoshHistory) {
      Get-History | Select-Object -Last 1  | Export-Csv $Env:MyPoshHistory -Append
    }
     'PS ' + $pwd + '> ' 
   }
```